# Reshaping array of matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a Numpy array `X` of `n` 2x2 matrices, arranged so that `X.shape = (2,2,n)`, that is, to get the first matrix I call `X[:,:,0]`. I would like to reshape `X` into an array `Y` such that I can get the first matrix by calling `Y[0]` etc., but performing `X.reshape(n,2,2)` messes up the matrices. How can I get it to preserve the matrices while reshaping the array?

I am essentially trying to do this:

```
import numpy as np
Y = np.zeros([n,2,2])
for i in range(n):
    Y[i] = X[:,:,i]
```

but without using the for loop. How can I do this with `reshape` or a similar function?

(To get an example array `X`, try `X = np.concatenate([np.identity(2)[:,:,None]] * n, axis=2)` for some `n`.)

Comment: `Y = X.transpose(2,0,1)` I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) can be used to take a view of an array with one axis moved to a different position in the shape:

```
numpy.moveaxis(X, 2, 0)
```

`numpy.moveaxis(a, source, destination)` takes a view of array `a` where the axis originally at position `source` ends up at position `destination`, so `numpy.moveaxis(X, 2, 0)` makes the original axis 2 the new axis 0 in the view.

There's also [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy.transpose), which can be used to perform arbitrary rearrangements of an array's axes in one go if you pass it the optional second argument, and [`numpy.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html), an older version of `moveaxis` with a more confusing calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

Use `swapaxis`:

```
Y = X.swapaxes(0,2)
```